# Run-time input to objSell.exec method in vbscript

Tags: svn, vbscript

I need to use subversion command line tools(svn.exe) in my vbscript as,

```
cmd = "c:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe " & "list " &   "https://10.0.3.133/svn/MyRepos"
Set oExec  = objShell.Exec (cmd)
OutPut = oExec.StdOut.ReadAll
Wscript.Echo Output
```

But This command need run-time input( (R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?) to accept the certificate.

How can i give run-time input to the objShell.exec command ?

Note: I have tried with SendKeys(), but not working.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I normally use:

```
Set WshShell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd"
WScript.Sleep 100 
WshShell.AppActivate "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
WScript.Sleep 100 
wshshell.sendkeys """c:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe"" list https://10.0.3.133/svn/MyRepos"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 100 
wshshell.sendkeys "P"
```